# How to determine valid NuGet package version combinations for NanoFramework

Tags: .net-core, esp32, nanoframework

I am building a .NET NanoFramework demo using the ESP32_VROOM_32 board.  I'm having trouble figuring our the correct combination of NuGet packages to avoid getting an assembly mismatch error when I try to debug my solution on the actual hardware.  This error I keep getting when I push to the device is:

```
[Found assemblies mismatches when checking for deployment pre-check.]
```

The combination of packages I currently have installed are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AMQPNetLite.nanoFramework" version="2.3.0.39" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.CoreLibrary" version="1.7.3-preview.4" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32" version="1.2.1-preview.12" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.ResourceManager" version="1.0.0-preview.15" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.Runtime.Events" version="1.4.2-preview.8" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.Runtime.Native" version="1.4.0-preview.1" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Collections" version="1.0.1-preview.7" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Math" version="1.2.0-preview.16" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Net" version="1.4.1-preview.21" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Text" version="1.0.0-preview.22" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
</packages>
```

My question is, is there a reliable systematic way to determine which combination of NuGet packages will work together with the firmware installed on the device?

I have tried many different combinations and can't get anything to work.

Currently, I have `1.4.0-preview.208` firmware installed on the ESP32, which appears to be the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relation between the versioning of the C# libraries and the native firmware implementation. That's because each part has it's own separate development cycle.
The declaration is on **which** native version it requires. From managed to native, not the other way around.

This is showned on the NuGet description. If you want to learn more about this, take a look at this blog post [here](https://www.nanoframework.net/nuget-assembly-and-native-versions).

In the meantime know that stable releases have been published for all class libraries and firmware. The links for the firmware images have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Each NuGet package has a declaration on which other packages it depends on and which version. There is no other way to determine a valid package combination.

The fw version you have loaded it's not a stable version, therefore the "preview" in the version. But neither are the NuGets. Which is all OK: if you are using the "preview" firmware you have to use the "preview" NuGets.

Can you post here the error message about the version mismatch that you get? This will help determine what is wrong there.

Comment: It doesn't seem as simple as you suggest.  For example, the mscorlib versions seem to have to match, and the firmware documentation for the latest ESP32 firmware does not mention which mscorlib version is needed.  My project has the latest Nanoframework extension added which I believe is using version 1.7.3..  If I list the ESP32 capabilities via VS 2019 it says that it is running 100.4.10.0.  I have no idea if these are compatible - I'm guessing they are not.

Comment: Furthermore, the latest ESP firmware shown at http://docs.nanoframework.net/content/reference-targets/esp32-wroom-32.html is now 1.5.0-preview.1 (which I have installed) - with no 'stable' entry.  As mscorlib is not a NuGet project it is not clear to me how to pull a version that is compatible with the ESP32 firmware or even what that version would be.  Also, some of the libraries do not even have a 'non-preview' version, e.g., nanoFramework.System.Text, so there isn't a stable version to choose from.

Comment: Another example, if I used the earliest version of nanoFramework.ResourceManager (v1.0.0-preview.1), this depends on nanoFramework.CoreLibrary >= 1.4.0-preview.3 - the last stable version of this library is 1.3.0.  So, you can see, just using the latest 'stable' versions is not practical - it just doesn't work that way.  I'd already included the error message I get when trying to push ([Found assemblies mismatches when checking for deployment pre-check.]).  This is the only error message - the project builds with no errors.

Comment: I am also waiting on an answer to this question.  Right now, I'm wondering if TinyCLR is a better choice (compared to NF)?

Comment: @DaveRobinson this has been answered. Back in June, there were a couple of mismatches in the referenced libraries. That last for a couple of days, until the situation was reported and promptly fixed. Right now everything is working smoothly.